# Greengrass v2 logging from within the component

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I am unable to see anything that I may log out of a Greengrass v2 component.

For example:

```
import logging
...
...
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

...
...
logger.info("Hello world")
```

This will not be visible in my .log or greengrass.log files. I've tried different logging levels too. and with `logger.debug("...")`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up configuring my logging to:

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Python with the `-u` argument to disable output buffering? Without this argument, Python scripts might not output logs.

See this troubleshooting entry: [Python script doesn't log messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/troubleshooting.html#python-component-no-log-output)